# Android how to reuse Socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, http-protocols

how to reuse TCP Socket connection(possible setReuseAddress(true), but not work for me) for download multiple files from Server(Apache, HTTPD) in on connection without disconnect(and connect again).

My code below..

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {

                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(serverIpAddress, SERVERPORT);
                socket = new Socket();

                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                socket.setSoLinger(true, 3000);
                socket.connect(sockaddr);

                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

                    output.println("GET /way/images/profile/1231 HTTP/1.1");
                    output.println("Host: 192.168.1.2");
                    output.println("User-Agent: Java");
                    output.println("Accept: */*");
                    output.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
                    output.println("");
                    output.flush();

                    String line;
                    File file = new File("/sdcard/aaa.png");
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    System.out.println("Getting first file");
                    while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null ) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        fileOut.write(line.getBytes());
                    }
                    System.out.println("First file finished");
                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();

                    output.println("GET /way/images/profile/1231 HTTP/1.1");
                    output.println("Host: 192.168.1.2");
                    output.println("User-Agent: Java");
                    output.println("Accept: */*");
                    output.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
                    output.println("");
                    output.flush();

                    file = new File("/sdcard/aaa1.png");
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    System.out.println("Getting second file");
                    while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null ) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        fileOut.write(line.getBytes());
                    }
                    System.out.println("Second file finished");

                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();
                    input.close();
                    output.close();

                }
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }

            finally {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "Socket: Closed.");
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: (1) Define 'not work for me'. (2) Do you mean how to reuse a *port?* (3) Testing `Socket.isConnected()` the next line after `Socket.connect()` is pointless. If it wasn't connected it would have thrown an exception so you would never get there.

Comment: (1)I use setReuseAddress(true), but cant reuse socket after first response from server(server not send second response).(2) I want reuse socket connection(maybe port),(3) Thanks, I already test code..

Comment: Thanks, now please define 'cannot reuse socket'. What do you mean by 'reuse'; what is your expectation; and what happens instead?

Comment: I mean that  setReuseAddress(true) doesn't work properly it is mean that socket connect to the server only one time, but second response returned empty

Comment: I'm not following you. Why are you connecting the socket more than once (sure that should work, but isn't the point to keep the socket connected and just send data up and down?)

Comment: You cannot connect a Socket more than once. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I dont want connect several times. I want - get many responses from server with http/1.1 protocol, in connected Socket. when I after first response again send request to server with http protocol, I received empty response(without anymore).

Answer (score 0):

setReuseAddress(true) prior to binding the socket allows the socket to be bound even though a previous connection is in a timeout state.

[documentation of setReuseAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29)

I don't see sense in directly using socket for HTTP communication. I use HttpURLConnection. Works without problems in most cases.